# Syntax highlighting in Oracle browser something like SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, oracle, syntax, highlighting

Hi I use long time MS SQL and SQL Server Management Studio no I start with oracle and try some SQL command in Oracle browser but it hasn’t any syntax highlighting.

It exist something like SQL Server Mamagement Studio for Oracle?

[image]

Comment: You can always use a programmers text editor that supports SQL syntax highlighting, like notepad++ or editpad. Of course, you can write your SQL in SSMS and run it on Oracle.

Comment: Or use Oracle SQL Developer, which is free.

Comment: I would like omited copy from editor and paste to oracle browser.

Comment: Or use Toad which isn't free but used to be more liked by the devs in my teams than Oracle SQL Developer http://www.quest.com/oracle/development.aspx

Comment: you don't have to copy to the browser, you can directly execute queries from SQL Develeper / Toad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are happy with installing something locally (or at least unzipping it), go with Xavinou's suggestion of [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) or one of the commercial IDEs such as TOAD or PL/SQL Developer