# Syntax Highlighting for Oracle Express

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-apex

Is there way to highlight SQL commants in Oracle Database Express editon (10g).
I want to see `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE` etc commants in different color.

[image]

Comment: No. but there are some solutions on this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129520/syntax-highlighting-in-oracle-browser-something-like-sql-server-management-studi?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129520/syntax-highlighting-in-oracle-browser-something-like-sql-server-management-studi?rq=1

Comment: I use Toad for writing/viewing code then just paste it back into APEX. I understand SQL Developer is free which also has syntax highlighting. This obviously means copying/pasting into/out of APEX, but it's better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

No, not out of the box. It seems you are on a version < 4.0, so taht might complicate it a bit.
You could try looking into apexLib: http://apexlib.oracleapex.info/
Although you would need firefox + greasemonkey extension or chrome to get this running. On IE it's a no-go.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome latest version. What do you mean about version 4.0? It is Oracle Database 10g Express edition. How can i learn which version i am using?

Comment: the oracle database is just that, the oracle database. Oracle apex is another product which runs on the database. You can see the version of your apex installation in the lower right of your screens i believe.

Comment: Application Express 2.1.0.00.39